# Oracle Array Binding resulting in truncated data

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I'm using Array Binding to import a series of Python scripts into an Oracle database:

```
using (OracleCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"insert into scripts (nscript, scriptname, scriptdescr, scripttext, created, modified, createdby) 
            values (nscript.nextval, :1, :2, :3, sysdate, sysdate, 'XXX')";

    OracleParameter paramScriptName = new OracleParameter("ScriptName", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 64);
    paramScriptName.Value = scriptNames.ToArray();

    OracleParameter paramScriptDescription = new OracleParameter("ScriptDescripption", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 128);
    paramScriptDescription.Value = scriptDescriptions.ToArray();

    OracleParameter paramScriptText = new OracleParameter("ScriptText", OracleDbType.Long, 0);
    paramScriptText.Value = scriptTexts.ToArray();

    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramScriptName);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramScriptDescription);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(paramScriptText);

    cmd.ArrayBindCount = scriptNames.Count;

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    paramScriptName.Dispose();
    paramScriptDescription.Dispose();
    paramScriptText.Dispose();
}
```

Following this guide: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2009/09-sep/o59odpnet-085168.html

However, I've noticed that some of the longer scripts are truncated when imported.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Steve

Comment: Why do you use the `Long` and `0` size in this line: `OracleParameter paramScriptText = new OracleParameter("ScriptText", OracleDbType.Long, 0);`?

Comment: Wasn't too sure what else to specify, but I've seen it elsewhere. That particular constructor insists on the size argument.

Comment: For what it's worth, the problem doesn't resolve itself if I increase that number drastically.

Comment: What is the type of the `scripttext` column in the database table? Shouldn't it hold `Varchar2` data?

Comment: It's LONG in the table definition.

Comment: What is the database version? Is it in your reach to modify the `scripttext` column type from `LONG` to `CLOB` ?

Comment: It's 11g R2. Unfortunately I can't change the column type.

Comment: Have you tried to use `cmd.Prepare();` just before the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` line?

Comment: FYI Turns out this is a limitation of inserting into Oracle LONG columns. The general recommendation is to convert the column to CLOB type. I can't do this so I'm still stuck but will continue to look for a workaround.